# Run code at Pyramid shutdown

Tags: python, pyramid

Pyramid supports an `ApplicationCreated` event. However I can't find any `ApplicationDestroyed`/`ApplicationShutdown` event. Is it at all possible do execute a function upon shutdown.

Do I have any choice other than to go further up my stack: ie. I'm using gevent inside uWSGI. It might be possible to get gevent or uWSGI to run my shutdown code, but it certainly isn't as pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyramid does not support any shutdown event.

However Python has a `atexit` event, that runs on interpreter shutdown

http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    print "You are now leaving the Python sector."
```