# Pyramid: run code at exit

Tags: mongodb, pyramid, pymongo

How would you run an exit script on pyramid that have access to configuration settings?

I want to close the database connection when exiting the server or when there's an error, but cannot find a way to access the exit loop. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484366/run-code-at-pyramid-shutdown), but I don't know how to access the Configurator object to close the connection that way.

Comment: Relevant: Bug report about this issue on the pyramid project page - https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/442

Comment: Hmmm, what WSGI server are you using? I figured out a way to do this in CherryPy, and it looks like there is a way [in gunicorn](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2012-February/005116.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since pyramid is persistence agnostic, it is not responsible for closing database connections. 
Your application most probably uses `pymongo` to connect to MongoDB. It is up to the `pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient` class to care about that.

After reading [MongoDB and Pyramid](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database/mongodb.html) you could read how [pinto](https://github.com/wwitzel3/pinto/blob/master/pinto/pinto/core/__init__.py#L22) (a more recent work) is managing connections to MongoDB since [pyramid_mongo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_mongodb) was not updated to latest PyMongo API.

Despite some differences in acquiring DB connection for the lifecycle of a request both use a [pyramid feature "add_finished_callback"](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#using-finished-callbacks) to close DB connection at the very end of a request (excerpt from docs: *even if an exception happens in application code that prevents a response from being generated.*) - exactly your requirement. Means as well, that all external DB connections are already closed, when pyramid shuts down and runs the code you actually want to hook in.

Comment: I'm not saying pyramid should close connections, I want to access the exit loop so I can close the connection through `pymongo.Connection`, the problem is I can't find out how to...

Comment: pyramid_mongo looks outdated, added note about pinto, extended my answer